Error Code 1329 when attempting nested Loops in MYSQL 8
I am working on a stored procedure and I have a rather complicated set of instructions in this query. (I apologize for the odd variable names, I had to mask data)
I have delcared a variable varId and am using a cursor to assign that value during a loop (curseLoop). I have created a second cursor where I need to use that varId in a WHERE clause.
When I execute the stored procedure I get Error Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed.
How do I fix this, or is my procedure structure completely wrong here?
   CREATE PROCEDURE `build_roster`(
    IN idList VARCHAR(255) -- comma separated string of contract ids
    )
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT;
    DECLARE doneAgain INT;
    
    -- variable for the first select statement to retrieve the billing id
    
    DECLARE varId INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    -- variable set that will build the roster table based on the billing id 
    
    DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE var2 VARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE var3 DATETIME;
    DECLARE var4 DATETIME;
    DECLARE var5 DATETIME;
    DECLARE var6 INT;
    
    -- buffer for outside loop
    DECLARE curse CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id from billing_file WHERE FIND_IN_SET(contract_id, contract_id_list);
    
    -- buffer for interior loop
    DECLARE secondCurse CURSOR FOR
        Select c.col1, c.col2, p.colA, p.colB, p.colC, cl.col from tableC c
        INNER JOIN tableP p ON c.col1 = p.colA
        INNER JOIN tableCL cl ON c.col2 = cl.col2A
        where c.miscCol = varId -- this is where I'm having an issue I think
        GROUP BY c.col1, c.col2, p.colA, p.colB
        ORDER BY p.colB ASC;
    
    -- set up the temporary table to house all the data that we find through the loops
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS results;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results (
        var1 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      var2 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      var3 DATETIME NOT NULL,
      var4 DATETIME,
      var5 DATETIME,
      var6 TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
    );
    
    -- begin parsing the data
    OPEN curse;

    curseLoop : LOOP
        FETCH curse INTO varId;
        OPEN secondCurse;
        secondCurseLoop : LOOP
            FETCH secondCurse INTO var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6;
            INSERT INTO results VALUES (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6);
        END LOOP secondCurseLoop;
        CLOSE secondCurse;
    END LOOP curseLoop;
    CLOSE curse;

    -- run a quick select to verify data is pulled, this is the stopping point for this procedure      build until I verify it all works
    SELECT * FROM results;
END

I ran the procedure as CALL build_roster("14,15"); using MySQL Workbench.
I was expecting an output of rows consisting of var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6. I did not received that data.

Do you really need nested loops? Why not just combine both queries into a single query with another join?

My SQL isn't up to a full answer, but it seems to me that your loops can be replaced by creating a SELECT that includes another JOIN to include the billing_file. If you get that right your results table can be created and populated with a CREATE TABLE...SELECT (Ref). The entire job is done in a single command. Do you still need a procedure?

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression or execution point where you don't get what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.
